# Insert array of objects into Core Data with Magical Record

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm a rookie with Core Data and magical record and I'm having problems to insert data.

**Webservice that returns JSON:**

[image]

**Core data Database:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Objective-C Code**

```
- (void)fetchDocumentsOnCompletion:(void(^) (NSDictionary *data,NSError *error))completionBlock
{
    [self GET:@"documents" parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

        NSArray *documentsArray = [Document MR_importFromArray:responseObject[@"documents"]];

        [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
            [Document MR_importFromArray:documentsArray inContext:localContext];
        } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

        }];



    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        completionBlock(nil, error);
    }];

}
```

If I put a breakpoint below of

```
NSArray *documentsArray = [Document MR_importFromArray:responseObject[@"documents"]];
```

the array has this value:

[image]

But when I remove the breakpoint and compile again, I get this crash:

[image]

I don't find the error, can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use _id as name of the property and not id

Comment: The core data editor does not allow me to write _id. Automatically change it to id

Answer (score 0):

To save and fetch data using MagicalRecord you need to save the data in a local context and then ask for the objects unique ID. Then use a predicate to retrieve them.

I'm using something similar in my code:

```
- (void)fetchDocumentsOnCompletion:(void(^) (NSArray *data, NSError *error))completionBlock
{
    [self GET:@"documents" parameters:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {


        // Create an array that's going to save all your unique
        // newly created object ids
        // 
        NSMutableArray *objectIDs = [NSMutableArray array];

        [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

            NSArray *documentsArray = [Document MR_importFromArray :responseObject[@"documents"] inContext:localContext];


            // Obtain Permanent Id used to retrieve objects after
            // it's being saved
            //
            NSError *error;
            if ([localContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:documentsArray error:&error]) {
                for (NSManagedObject *obj in documentsArray) {
                    [objectIDs addObject:[obj objectID]];
                }
            }

        } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

            // Fetch items
            //
            id newlyCreatedItemsNowInMainContext = !error ? [Document findAllWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self IN %@", objectIDs]] : nil)
            if (completionBlock)
                completionBlock(newlyCreatedItemsNowInMainContext, error)
        }];

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        completionBlock(nil, error);
    }];
}
```

Comment: I followed your answer but it is repeating the results. See Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634680/magicalrecord-creating-duplicate-result-for-objectid